# Laravel - How to filter hasMany relation based on parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Restaurant Model :

```
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'id_restaurant');
    }

}
```

with a hasMany relation with Order.

What i want to do is to get Restaurant with Orders between some dates.

```
Restaurant::whereHas('orders' , function($q) use($startDate, $endDate){

                $q->where('created_at', '>=', $startDate->toDateTimeString())->where('created_at', '<=', $endDate->toDateTimeString());

            })
```

This is what i tried but is not good.
In other words i want to filter the relation of a Model by some parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [with](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
Restaurant::with(['orders'=>  function($q) use($startDate, $endDate){

        $q->whereBetweeen('created_at',  [$startDate,$endDate]);

    }])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you.That was the answer but "whereBetween" translates to  "where ' between'" and is not working .